# Change class background-color property on click of div with angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I have created a custom rectangle with 4 colors as follows,

```
 <div style=" width:400; height:400; float:left">
 <div style="background-color:red; width:50%; height:50%; float:left">
 </div>
 <div style="background-color:blue; width:50%; height:50%; float:right">
 </div>
 <div style="background-color:green; width:50%; height:50%; float:left">
 </div>
 <div style="background-color:orange; width:50%; height:50%; float:right">
 </div>
 </div>
```

I need to change the following class's background-color property same as above div ones on click of above div's

```
<div class="eventBox eventBox__colorBar"></div>
```

Comment: Please, provide more info. I really can't understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of doing what you need using jquery.
Html:

```
<div style=" width:400; height:400; float:left">
  <div class="div-class" style="background-color:red; width:50%; height:50%; float:left">
    test1
  </div>
  <div class="div-class" style="background-color:blue; width:50%; height:50%; float:right">
    test 2
  </div>
  <div class="div-class" style="background-color:green; width:50%; height:50%; float:left">
    test3
  </div>
  <div class="div-class" style="background-color:orange; width:50%; height:50%; float:right">
    test4
  </div>
</div>
<div class="eventBox eventBox__colorBar">
  test5
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".div-class").click(function() {
  $(".eventBox").css('color', this.style.backgroundColor);
});
```

I've assigned a class name for each of the divs and hooked a click event using that class name.

Comment: Question is with angular2

Comment: @Sajeetharan, you tagged it with `jQuery`.